# Yahoo OAuth 2.0 throws error as Cycle detected

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, yahoo-api

I am implementing yahoo OAuth 2.0. After a lot of struggle, I was able to get the authorization code.

When I try to get the access token in exchange for the authorization code, i get the error as follows

`Description: Could not process your request for the document
because it would cause an HTTP proxy cycle. Please check the URL and your
browser's proxy settings.`

I get this type of error randomly when i try to navigate from my app to yahoo authentication page. Can anyone give some details if they have overcome this problem.

I am not using any owin middleware and making a plain `HttpClient` based request

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from yahoo side, i have checked a lot of forums and got to this conclusion. Whenever you see it just press F5 once and it will go for your that session.

Comment: I am getting the error when making the request via httpclient programmatically. I cannot refresh in that point of time

Comment: if it is your web application, when you see this error press F5, if you see it  again press F5. That's the only solution, because that some sort of thing coming from yahoo. If you see this error is also the same in twitter when you press the yahoo button for sending your contact list in yahoo. So just F5 wherever you see.

Comment: Since hitting F5 is not the only solution, I have posted on yahoo forum. I'll post the solution here based on the reply